# Does a ++ inside a lock() block get applied differently when run from the Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I was trying to debug an issue today with duplicate ids in our application, and I noticed that running code from the Immediate Window does not act as expected. Here is my sample program I was using to test :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A: {0}", a.Id));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("B: {0}", b.Id));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ClassA
{
    private static int _id = MySingleton.Instance.GetId(typeof(ClassA));

    public int Id { get { return _id; } }
}

public class ClassB
{
    private static int _id = MySingleton.Instance.GetId(typeof(ClassB));

    public int Id { get { return _id; } }
}

public class MySingleton
{
    private int _id = 0;
    private object lockObj = new object();
    Dictionary<string, int> _cache = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    private static readonly MySingleton _mySingleton = new MySingleton();

    public int GetId(Type t)
    {
        if (_cache.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
        {
            return _cache[t.FullName];
        }
        else
        {
            lock (lockObj)
            {
                Add(t.FullName, _id++);
                return _id;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(string key, int value)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(key))
            _cache.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get { return _mySingleton; }
    }
}
```

If I run this code, the output is

```
A: 1
B: 2
```

But if I put a breakpoint the `static int _id` and check the value of `MySingleton.Instance.GetId(typeof(ClassA))` in the Immediate window, then it shows me a value of `1` the first time, put persists `0`, so the output is :

```
A: 0
B: 2
```

If I put the breakpoint in ClassB and run `MySingleton.Instance.GetId(typeof(ClassA))` in the Immediate window, it shows me a value of `2` the first time, but persists as `1` for any subsequent calls:

```
A: 1
B: 1
```

What I would actually expect because I am using `_id++` instead of `++_id` is that the output should be

```
A: 0
B: 1
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a few observations:

1. When you call `GetID` the first time, the cache is not filled for that type. The value is added to te cache and then increased. But that increased (and I assume incorrect) value is returned (`1` for `ClassA`), NOT the value inside the cache, which is lower. So if you call `GetID` a second time for the same type, you get a value that is one lower (`0` for `ClassA`).
2. When you use your debugger and watch results, those "watches" might modify the results. In your case: The watch window shows the incorrect value (`1` for `ClassA`), and after that, de program uses the correct value (`0` for `ClassA`).

Try to fix your code like this:

```
lock (lockObj)
{
    Add(t.FullName, _id); // <-- remove the ++
    return _id++; // <-- add the ++
}
```

This way, the orignal value of _id is returned before it is incremented.

Another observation:

3. You are using a `Dictionay<K,V>`. This one is not threadsafe. You should not only protect it with a lock during write-operations, but also during a read-operation. With your code as it is now, a read-during-a-write-operation might lead to bad results. Consider using the `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: You're right! The 0 is added to cache while 1 is returned because of the sequence of operations! *"Add `_id` to cache, increase `_id`, return `_id`"*. Ok, that solves one of my issues at least, thank you! I've been trying to debug this issue too long I think :) And in regards to point 3, a `Dictionary` is not actually used here but I used it for my test project because of it's simplicity.

Comment: Nice to hear you are one step further. If your question is fully answer, please use the tick to make it the correct answer. If you still have issues unanswered in your question, I would like to help you further.

Comment: That does indeed answer both this question, and the bug I was tracking down! In this case, initial value of `_id` was the Max from a cache file, so anytime new objects were added to the application, there was one duplicate being added. Thank you!